# can't create admin from admin account at Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, admin

i'm trying to make an `Jmeter` request to create administrator from admin user. I get 200 answer back, but actually there is no administrator that was created.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: can you check application log what was wrong/missing in request?

Comment: at jmeter there is no error or missing, also if i'm making the same procedure but produce regular user and not admin user so it works, so there is something  with the creation of admin only

Comment: Are you able to create admin without JMeter? What's the differences? You need to provide more info if it's connected to JMeter

Comment: yes, i manage to create admin without Jmeter, maybe there is something i get when i create only the admin and these the thing i need for the rest of the procedure?

Comment: You need to capture your request and check if you use cookie or send another unique id or submit other requests before

Comment: how can i compare between the POST and the GET to know what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

This "HTTP 200" indication of success is a false positive accepted by many performance testers.   Think back to testing 101, for each step there is a positive and expected result for the step.   If you do not receive that expected result then you should branch your test code and discontinue the execution of your business process.

Take a look at the content within pages being returned for each step.  Do not simply accept  an HTTP 200 as an indicator of success, because the content on the page may be inappropriate for the condition you expect.

This answer is tool independent as the problem of not checking content crosses users of all performance testing tools and cross protocols.

Comment: agreed, that's why i asked .
i know i see the 200 but it's false positive cause actually there is no admin that was created, only in end users creation it works